# Matplotlib - setting tick positions on a specific subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying something like this:

```
vol_grid = MultipleLocator(1000)
fig_vol = plt.subplot2grid((count, count), (i, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=count)
fig_vol.yaxis.set_major_locator(vol_grid)
```

but it has no effect. Any ideas?

My intention is to set the labels on the y-axis 1000 units apart, i.e. have labels at 1000, 2000, 3000, etc.

Comment: `fig_vol.set_yticks([1000, 2000, 3000, ...])` should work...

Comment: I'd love to try it, but now all of a sudden I started getting something like 
 /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1224: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['monospace'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
      (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
    /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:239: FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png formatter: Locator attempting to generate 20001 ticks from 0.0 to 100.0: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS
      FormatterWarning,
without even changing the code. Any idea?

Comment: unfortunately I don't know... something probably changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't plotted anything, and thats is why the tick labels are not showing (the `ylim` defaults to `(0,1)`, you can set `vol_grid = MultipleLocator(0.1)` to see that)

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vol_grid = MultipleLocator(1000)
fig_vol = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=2)
fig_vol.yaxis.set_major_locator(vol_grid)
```

[image]

We can change the `ylim` or just plot some data:

```
fig_vol.set_ylim(1000, 9000)
#plt.plot([1,2,3], [1000, 2000, 5000])
```

[image]